# Prevent breaking encapsulation

Tags: c++, encapsulation, getter

I have this class:

```
class Phone {
private:
    string producer, color;
    int weight, dimension;
public:
    Phone(string &producer, string &color, int &weight, int &dimension):
        producer(producer), color(color), weight(weight), dimension(dimension) {};
    Phone():
        producer(""), color(""), weight(0), dimension(0) {};
    virtual ~Phone() {};
    string getProducer(void) const;
    string getColor(void) const;
    int getWeight(void) const;
    int getDimension(void) const;
    virtual void displayInfo(void) const;
};
```

The problem is here caused by the fact that I expose the internal implementation of the object via getters.

But how can I prevent this?

Because usually in my code, I need to know some private data from my object (for comparision is one example), and that's why I use getters.

So then I rewrite the class to something like this:

```
class Phone {
    private:
        string producer, color;
        int weight, dimension;
    public:
        Phone(string &producer, string &color, int &weight, int &dimension):
            producer(producer), color(color), weight(weight), dimension(dimension) {};
        Phone():
            producer(""), color(""), weight(0), dimension(0) {};
        virtual ~Phone() {};
        bool isTheProducer(string& producer) const { return this->producer == producer };
        bool hasWeight(int& weight) const { return this->weight == weight };
        bool hasDimension(int& dimension) const { return this->dimension == dimension };
        virtual void displayInfo(void) const;
    };
```

Is this a better design (by the fact that I don't get the actual private value)?

Comment: What is wrong with getters without setters actually?

Comment: What do you mean by "the problem"? For me the first code looks like a totally valid class you would find in nearly every OOP-language.

Comment: "*The problem is here caused by the fact that I expose the internal implementation of the object via getters."* And why is this bad? If they have a `Phone` and want to know the `weight` or `dimension` that is the most straight forward way to access it.

Comment: @Cyber It’s bad because it violates the guideline known as “[tell, don’t ask](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk)”. To pick up OP’s example of comparing objects: this should be done *inside* the object, not outside.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree with "comparing objects: this should be done inside the object". But OP gives in the second code example a compare method for each member, which in fact does not reduce the amount of knowledge required about the internal representation. If the point is about comparing two Phone instances, than there should be a method like "bool isEqualTo(Phone&)" or even better a overloaded == operator.

Comment: @BDL Yes, OP’s second code isn’t really better than the first in that regard.

Comment: Just to clearify a little bit more: As far as I remember the "tell,  don't ask" only applies to situations where the state of the object is changed depending on a out-of-object state decision. Example: It  is against the rule to do something like `if (phone.getWeight() < 10) { phone.setColor("RED"); }`, but it is perfectly fine to have a code snipped like `if (phone.getWeight() < 10) { cout << "It's below"; }` since here the state of the object is not changed. To sum it up: Not the getter itself is evil, only the usage of it can be.

Comment: @BDL Yes I agree, but in sum, good application of the principle shows that most conventional uses of getters are in fact at least questionable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph To cut the discussion a bit, I wrote a more detailed answer. But I bet there are a lot of things to improve in it, so feel free to point them out, I will edit them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have seen from the other answers and comments, the answer is: It depends.

In fact, it depends mainly on the usecases where your class is used. Let's stick first to the example given in the question, the comparison of objects. Since it is not clearly visible from the question if we want to compare two phone objects or just a specific data member I will discuss both situations here.

**Comparing a data member to out-of-class data**

Let's take this usecase where we search for all phones with a weight bigger than x(just pseudocode):

```
for (Phone& p in phoneList) {
    if (p.getWeight() > x) {
        cout << "Found";
    }
}
```

Then the first class example is perfectly fine, since this is not an intrinsic feature of the phone, and thus the phone class is not responsible for handling it. In addition, the result does not expose more than absolutely required for the task.

**Comparing two phone objects**

In this case both code examples are equally good (or in this case equally bad). In both cases the user has to know a lot of details about how phones are represented to compare all necessary members. If in a later revision a new member is added to the class, every code segment that compares two phones has to be adapted. To overcome this, one can add a function to the class that does exactly the comparison.

```
class Phone {
private:
    string producer, color;
    int weight, dimension;
public:
    bool IsEqualTo(const Phone& other)
    {
        return (producer == other.producer && color == other.color &&....);
    }
```

**Non comparitive usecase**

But let's go to a more advanced example. Let's assume the following task: A user enters the pin to a phone and if it is the correct one, the phone should unlock. Let's assume a very naive approach:

```
class Phone
{
private:
    int pin;
    bool unlocked;

public:
    int getPin() { return pin; }
    void unlock() { unlocked = true; }
};
```

and the corresponding call

```
if (phone.getPin() == enteredPin)
    phone.unlock();
```

In this case we have a totally different situation. Here we need to consider the ["tell, don't ask"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk) rule, which basically says that it is a bad design to query the state of an object first, make a decision and then tell the object what to do. Instead we should only tell the object what we want, and let it do the work for us. In this usecase this is obvious, since unlocking the phone only when the pin is correct is a responsibility of the phone, not of the user that uses the phone class. But in more complex scenarious many programmers will do exactly what I described here.

Back to the problem: A good solution here would be for example

```
class Phone
    {
    private:
        int pin;
        bool unlocked;

    public:
        void CheckPin(int enteredPin) {
            if (pin == enteredPin)
               unlocked = true;
        }
    };
```

with the code

```
phone.CheckPin(enteredPin);
```

Hope this helps, and thanks to @KonradRudolph for pointing to the "tell, don't ask rule". Feel free to help me to improve the answer per commenting on it :)

Answer (score 1):

The first one, even with getter, is encapsulated. Consider the `color()` method, which returns a string. Even if you change the implementation of `Phone` such that you store the color as an enum rather than a string, your method can still return a string if you do some sort of conversion first. The important part is that you can change the implementation of `color()` and the underlying storage without users of the class needing to change.

Compare to a class that stores color as a publicly accessible string. If you later change the data member to an enum, you need to modify every location that uses the color. This is less of a property of encapsulation and more a property of separating interface from implementation.

Comment: Repeating my comment from the other answer: the class may be somewhat “encapsulated”, but without the existence of getters they would be *more* encapsulated. Encapsulation exists on a scale, not as a binary value. “the important part is …” – no. That is just *one* important part of encapsulation.

Comment: Ok I'll concede on the picky wording of "the" vs "one". It obviously exists on a continuum, which can be as extreme as providing virtually no access to the contained data. But the question wasn't about which design was *more* encapsulated, he asked which was better, and that comes down to usage. `phone.isTheColor("blue")` is fine, but fails at design if the goal is for the client to learn the actual color, but getter is ok. I'm considering what `std::vector` would be like with an `.isTheSize(3)` member rather than `.size()` and I hope we can agree that it would be encapsulated but awful.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation allows controlling of attributes exclusively via methods within the class. Both examples are encapsulated.

Comment: “both examples are encapsulated” – yes, but without the existence of getters they would be *more* encapsulated. Encapsulation exists on a scale, not as a binary value.